# MSBuild ProjectReference item documentation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild

I cannot find documentation about `ProjectReference` tag in MSBuild projects. Where can I read detailed description of it?

**Edit:**
I have a `.vcxproj` created by others. It contains `ProjectReference` item. `ProjectReference` contains subtags: `Private`, `ReferenceOutputAssembly`, `CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies`, `LinkLibraryDependencies`, `UseLibraryDependencyInputs`. Where I can read about those tags? Which values can they contain? What other subtags can `ProjectReference` contain?

I have searched in MSDN and Google but have not found documentation pages, only discussions and documentation about other products, not MSBuild.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "detailed". You could start with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx). And of course Dr. Google will always be glad to help. What is it, that you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @Christian.K Word ReferenceOutputAssembly absents on the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx

Comment: @sergtk The original revision of the question, which I commented on, didn't mention the "Edit:" paragraph and thus didn't mention "ReferenceOutputAssembly"; the page I linked to was about the original revisions' "ProjectReference".

Comment: Some more info in MSBuild repo docs: [ProjectReference Protocol](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/documentation/ProjectReference-Protocol.md)

Answer (score 12):

Starting from the MSBuild source code links that Jason Pyeron provided in his comment, I learned that when MSBuild prepares build dependencies, [it includes all item metadata](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/e5bc7994348dba88d1f6fe2ebd6aa354355f0063/src/Tasks/AssemblyDependency/ReferenceTable.cs#L2758) (what you refer to as subtags) from each `ProjectReference` item. As a result, downstream Tasks and Targets can and sometimes do read arbitrary `ProjectReference` metadata.

For answers to your questions about C++ projects, you can examine `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets` and `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets` (their default path in MSBuild 14, coinciding with Visual Studio 2015, is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\`). As the following example shows, however, it is not simple to do so:

1. In `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets`, the Target `ResolvedXDCMake` creates `_ResolvedNativeProjectReferencePaths` Items dynamically.
2. From those Items, the Target `ComputeReferenceLinkInputs` creates `ProjectReferenceToLink` items dynamically.
3. For each of those Items that do not have `CopyLocal` metadata, the same Target adds it, copying any `Private` metadata value.
4. For each those Items with a distinct path, the same target creates a `Link` item dynamically.
5. Switching now to `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`, `Link` items are passed in the `Sources` parameter of the `Link` Task in the `Link` Target! Although to be fair, their metadata was cleared in the previous step, so you do not have to dive into the `Link` Target documentation in this particular case.

Here are additional portions that relate your question:

**Parameters**

- `Include` (attribute): Path to project file
- `Project` (metadata): Project GUID, in the form {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
- `ReferenceOutputAssembly` (metadata): Boolean specifying whether the
  outputs of the project referenced should be passed to the compiler.
  Default is true.
- `SpecificVersion` (metadata): Whether the exact version of the assembly should be used.
- `Targets` (metadata): Semicolon-separated list of targets in the referenced projects that should be built. Default is the value of `$(ProjectReferenceBuildTargets)` whose default is blank, indicating the default targets.
- `OutputItemType` (metadata): Item type to emit target outputs into. Default is blank. If `ReferenceOutputAssembly` is set to "true" (default) then target outputs will become references for the compiler.
- `EmbedInteropTypes` (metadata): Optional boolean. Whether the types in this reference need to embedded into the target assembly - interop asemblies only

**Remarks**

When the `OutputItemType` parameter is used, additional parameters (metadata) may be applicable. For example, when `OutputItemType` is set to `Content`, `CopyToOutputDirectory` can be used:

- CopyToOutputDirectory (metadata): Optional string. Determines whether to copy the file to the output directory. Values: `Never`, `Always`, `PreserveNewest`.

Answer (score 6):

You will notice that the ProjectReference element is a child of an ItemGroup element.

ItemGroups are a fully documented schema item thankfully.  What you will find is that child elements of ItemGroups can by anything.  Think of it as the name of a collection.  That item within the ItemGroup can have "metadata" values.

For example,

```
<ItemGroup>
    <WindowsFiles Include="C:\Windows\*">
       <IsSystem>true</IsSystem>
    </WindowsFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is defining an itemgroup called WindowsFiles.  It essentially becomes a collection of files that match the Include attribute.  All item group items have metadata built in - such as filename, extension, fullpath, directory, etc. but you can add your own - in this case IsSystem is an additional one.

Referencing item groups is done in one of two ways:

```
<Message Text="%(WindowsFiles.FullPath)"/>

<Message Text="@(WindowsFiles->'%(FullPath)')"/>
```

The latter is referred to as a transform which is more advanced.  Best stick to the former until you get your head around ItemGroups or transforms just won't go in.

The ProjectReference itemgroup you are interested in will be processed by a targets file somewhere.  As itemgroups are fairly arbitrary in what they are called, conceptually they are variables so it's how they get processed by the targets file that defines the usage.

Work your way up the files mentioned in the Import statements to see where the ProjectReference item group gets consumed.

Comment: You say they're fully documented, but don't include a reference to the documents.

Comment: Updated links, still not too helpful: [https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/Microsoft.Build.xsd](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/Microsoft.Build.xsd) and [https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/MSBuild/Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/MSBuild/Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd).