# What is the CMake equivalent to .vcxproj <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, dependencies

What is the correct translation of Visual Studio project file's `ReferenceOutputAssembly` tags in CMake terms?

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\commonStuff\commonStuff.vcxproj">
      <Project>{fffffff-fffff-ffff-ffff-ffffff}</Project>
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Assumption:

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    commonStuff
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Visual Studio project metadata element is used to specify whether or not the outputs of the referenced project are copied to the directory containing the outputs of the referencing project. Here's a brief [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary/) explaining the typical use case. If `ReferenceOutputAssembly` is not set, the default behavior is `true` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449912/3987854) answer).

The `ReferenceOutputAssembly` element in the Visual Studio project file is set by CMake based on whether or not the dependency is a **managed** target (i.e. C# target or a target compiled with `/clr`). There is no explicit way to set this with CMake commands.

If *none* of the following conditions apply to the target, the `ReferenceOutputAssembly` will be set to `false`:

- Dependency is a C# target
- Dependency is a [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2019) target
- Dependency is marked as a WinRT component (see [`VS_WINRT_COMPONENT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_WINRT_COMPONENT.html))

You can see how CMake sets the `ReferenceOutputAssembly` element in the CMake source. The logic for setting it to `false` is [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/95d4a2d05562c5f0a4113527d31dadef4d7756bd/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L4095), whereas the logic for setting it to `true` for .NET/C# targets is [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/95d4a2d05562c5f0a4113527d31dadef4d7756bd/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L858). There may be cases (e.g. a CMake project containing a mix of unmanaged C++ and C++/CLI) in which this field is not populated by CMake.

Comment: Oh so this is "from CMake's point of view". Are there any extra conditions (beside those three) why someone would opt to remove the line (via Visual Studio's GUI) ? A missing line would default to ´<ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>´ right? I am trying to understand some new codebase and differences between CMake's generated files and the original vcxproj (pointing out C++ here).

Comment: @bigla Yes, when you asked for "*...in CMake terms...*", I thought you wanted an explanation for CMake's handling of this project metadata. To answer your questions, I updated my post.

Comment: @bigla I added an explanation and a small article to explain the typical use case.